# Pass BASH array to diff like file contents

Tags: bash, io-redirection, diff, array

I have two `bash` arrays, say:

```
arr1=( 1 2 3 )
arr2=( 1 2 A )
```

and I want to compare them using `diff`. How could I pass the arrays as if they were the contents of a file?

I tried a few variations, but all failed:

```
diff -y <$( echo ${arr1[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' ) <$( echo ${arr2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' )
diff -y <${arr1[@]} <${arr2[@]}
diff -y $(<${arr2[@]}) $(<${arr1[@]})
diff -y  <<<"$( echo ${arr1[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' )" \
         <<<"$( echo ${arr2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' )"
```

Desired output would be the expected from `diff -y`, which I get if I store the arrays into files a and b:

```
diff a b
 1        1
 2        2
 3      | A
```

(less spaces for readability)

I would like to avoid writing intermediate files for speed reasons, although I am aware of `tmpfs` pseudo files as RAM-based workaround.

Comment: `<<<` is implemented by writing a file in `/tmp`, and redirecting input from that, unfortunately.  One of the inputs could be a pipe, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `printf` and [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```
diff -y  <(printf '%s\n' "${arr1[@]}")  <(printf '%s\n' "${arr2[@]}")
1                                                               1
2                                                               2
3                                                             | A
```

Comment: I see `<( )` is the trick, that way also my `<( echo ${arr1[@]} | tr ' '  '\n' )` works. I'll keep the "process substitution" keyword in mind.

Comment: @Fiximan, your `tr` pipeline will break for any array element containing spaces. `printf` is the idiomatic way to print an array one element per line.

Comment: I agree `printf` is saver if formulating it more general, although I will not have elements with spaces. Also every pipe avoided should be faster, so that also speaks for `printf` .... However, my main concern was getting the `<( )` solution.

Comment: "I will not have elements with spaces."  <- Famous last words!